# Regex.Replace - Replace string between two characters in a multi-line scenario

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Using Regex.Replace and C# I'm trying to replace all characters in between two delimiters however I'm struggling to do it in a multi-line scenario only on one single line.

My regex:

```
\<(.*?)\>
```

My data:

```
<
★ Gut Knife | Marble Fade (Factory New) - 40k
Shadow Case Key - 1k
AWP | Asiimov (Battle-Scarred) - 8k
AWP | Hyper Beast (Well-Worn) - 9k
StatTrak™ AWP | Redline (Minimal Wear) - 21k
Five-SeveN | Monkey Business (Field-Tested) - 1k
>
```

Now I know you can use `\s` to signal you want the regex to match newlines however any combination I try with the above Regex isn't working.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `<[^<>]*>` ..............

Comment: Post as answer ill mark it correct. Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negated character class `[^<>]` will also match a newline character since a dot won't unless you specify the dotall modifier `(?s)`

```
@"<[^<>]*>"
```

or

```
@"(?s)<.*?>"
```

Use the above regex in `Regex.Replace` and then replace the match with an empty string.

Comment: So the easiest way to find EVERYTHING in between two delimiters is to use a negated character class with the delimiters actually contained within it? I see, this was a great help thankyou!

Comment: Sometimes you see a funny face, but its just a regular expression.